# Lag values for supervised learning in sequence / time-series

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I try to figure out how to solve this problem in R. I want to use different machine learning regression models on time series data, which is in the area of supervised learning. In that case I need a function / package that allows me to go n-step forward and n-step back, like a sliding window function. The table shows the input (t-n) and output (t+n) variables with the current observation (t) considered an output.

```
       var1(t-1)  var2(t-1)  var1(t)  var2(t)  var1(t+1)  var2(t+1)
1        4           69        5       70         6       71
2        5           70        6       71         7       72
3        6           71        7       72         8       73
4        7           72        8       73         9       74
5        8           73        9       74        10       75
6        9           74        10      75        11       76
7        10          75        11      76        12       77
8        11          76        12      77        13       78
```

I already researched about some useful methods such as lag() or the shift() method at [r-blogger.com](https://www.r-bloggers.com/generating-a-laglead-variables/), but at these examples the problem is that missing values will generate.

```
    shift<-function(x,shift_by){
    stopifnot(is.numeric(shift_by))
    stopifnot(is.numeric(x))

    if (length(shift_by)>1)
        return(sapply(shift_by,shift, x=x))

    out<-NULL
    abs_shift_by=abs(shift_by)
    if (shift_by > 0 )
        out<-c(tail(x,-abs_shift_by),rep(NA,abs_shift_by))
    else if (shift_by < 0 )
        out<-c(rep(NA,abs_shift_by), head(x,-abs_shift_by))
    else
        out<-x
    out
}
```

Result of the shift() function:

```
    x df_lead2 df_lag2
1   5      4      NA
2   6      5      NA
3   7      6      5
4   8      7      6
5   9      8      7
6   10     9      8
7   11     10     9
8   12     11     10
9   13     NA     11
10  14     NA     12
```

So are there any packages or implemented functions, that allows to receive a dataframe and calculate for each variable the amount of indicates t-n or t+n?

Would be so nice if someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use rollapply (zoo):

```
rollapply(iris$Sepal.Length, width = 3, by = 2, FUN = mean, align = "left")
```

You can specify whether you want to compute values (or not) depending if there is a subsequent value (https://rdrr.io/cran/rowr/man/rollApply.html)

Comment: based on this comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/mean-of-a-sliding-window-in-r

Comment: I am not sure, if this approach is the right one. With the rollApply method it is possible to slide the window to the left or right side, but only by calculating the mean. I mean, for a dataset that consists of data such as A[201, 0.1, 10, 100] and I would use the mean function, the rolling value for the second record would be enormous high, right?

Comment: I am not sure what your desired result is, just the lead/lag value or any function applied to the leading/lagging values? Computing the mean is always dependent on outliers/extreme values but you can deal with this in numerous ways if desired

Comment: Well, one of my goal is to execute a random forest regression on my time serie data, so like a supervised learning problem. I can also predict the values for the test dataset. The other goal is, which is the most important ones, to use this model to predict 1day ahead for example. Because right now it is only possible to predict on the given data, without looking ahead. Yes of course there are several ways how to deal with outliers, I also thought about normalization to reduce the interval of these extreme values.

Comment: Hmm sounds rather complex, RF model can model the data within the range of features you specify, not data outside the chosen bounds estimated in the training set. Maybe check this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175908/random-forest-regression-and-trended-time-series